# Any Hotfix available for Windows 7 Ultimate or Windows 7 (no service packs installed) for auto updating Root certificates

Tags: windows-7, ssl-certificate

I am aware that a hotfix is available for Windows 7 service pack 1 "Support for urgent Trusted Root updates for Windows Root Certificate Program in Windows", but could not find a similar hotfix that is supported on Windows 7 (non service pack machines). Are there any similar hotfixes released for windows 7 machines without service pack1, if not available, is SHA2 certificate support a reason for not providing this hotfix to windows 7.

Comment: Windows 7 is EOL, hence it does not receive updates anymore unless you have a paid support from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

No, you must have SP1.
According to Microsoft KB - [Support for urgent Trusted Root updates for Windows Root Certificate Program in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3004394/support-for-urgent-trusted-root-updates-for-windows-root-certificate-p)

> Prerequisites
>
> To install this update, you must install update [2919355](https://support.microsoft.com/help/2919355) in Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2. Or, install [Service Pack 1](https://support.microsoft.com/help/976932) for Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2.

SP1 is 9 years old. No machine should still be running without it - because, apart from anything else, you would be about 250 other updates behind, too. [No machine should still be running Win7 at all, unless you have paid enterprise support] but SP1 has been a base requirement for many years.